# How to make TestNg run integration tests and junit5 run unit tests at the same pom, using surefire and failsafe?

Tags: java, maven, junit5

So I have a pom file, where I got junit5, and I got testng, and i'd like to achieve the following:
When running mvn verify -> first the unit tests would run using junit platform and then integration tests would run but testng would be the platform provider for integration tests ( I do have xml files).

And when running mvn package -> I want the surefire plugin to run only the junit platform and run the unit tests.

At the moment, I do see that when running mvn package it runs the unit tests using junit platform provider, which is good.

Also when running mvn verify it first runs the unit tests using the junit platform provider and run the unit tests which is great, but then it doesn't find the testng platform provider and it doesn't run any integration tests written inside the xml file.

Pom:

```
  <junit.jupiter.version>5.8.2</junit.jupiter.version>
  <testcontainers.version>1.17.2</testcontainers.version>
  <junit.platform.version>1.8.2</junit.platform.version>

 
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
             <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
             <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
             <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
             <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
             <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId>
             <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
             <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
         </dependency>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
             <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
         </dependency>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
             <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
             <version>7.9.0</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.support</groupId>
             <artifactId>testng-engine</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.1</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <plugins>
          <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>2.22.2</version>
                 <configuration>

                 </configuration>
                 <dependencies>
                     <dependency>
                         <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                         <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
                         <version>3.2.1</version>
                     </dependency>
                     <dependency>
                         <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                         <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                         <version>3.2.1</version>
                     </dependency>
                 </dependencies>
          </plugin>

          <plugin>
             <!-- The Failsafe plugin will look for **/IT\*.java, **/\*IT.java, and **/\*ITCase.java -->
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
             <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>integration-test</goal>
                         <goal>verify</goal>
                     </goals>
                 </execution>
             </executions>
             <configuration>
                 <suiteXmlFiles>
                     <file>src/test/resources/testng-first- 
                      suite.xml</file>
                     <file>src/test/resources/testng-second- 
                       suite.xml</file>
                 </suiteXmlFiles>
             </configuration>
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "intrigue" here? (You use it twice in the title but not at all in the body, and I'm basically confused by it.)

Comment: In simple:
I want mvn package to trigger unit tests which are written using junit5, and 
when running mvn verify I want it to trigger unit tests using junit5. junit platform provider, and then also trigger integration tests using testng platform provider..

Comment: So where does "intrigue" come in? Did you just mean "trigger" instead? (Those are very different words...)

Comment: Yes that’s exactly what I meant

Comment: Okay, so please edit your post to make it clear to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below `<dependencies>` section and `<plugins>` section should clarify how to do this.

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <surefire.version>3.2.5</surefire.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
                    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now you can run both your JUnit and TestNG tests using `mvn clean verify`.

Comment: Following question,
Could you please explain why adding surefire into failsafe makes it work?

Comment: surefire plugins rely on reflection to figure out what provider (basically which test framework to use based on what is first found on the classpath) to use. By explicitly adding the provider to the plugin dependencies, we are forcing surefire to use what we are providing rather than it trying to find out what exists. That is why the surefire plugin runs with JUnit and the failsafe bindings runs with TestNG